# what is the meaning of this integral joint pdf $ \int_a^b f_{xy}(x,y)dx$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I know that integrate over one variable on joint pdf will have marginal pdf of another variable, and iterated integral will have the joint probability.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{xy}(x,y)dx=f_y(y)\\
\int_a^b\int_c^df_{xy}(x,y)dxdy=F(c\leq X\leq d,a\leq Y\leq b)=P(c\leq X\leq d,a\leq Y\leq b)$$

Then I was intrigued by the meaning of this integral joint pmf $$ \int_a^b f_{xy}(x,y)dx=??$$

Appreciated for any help and comments.

Comment: You may want to see the conditional joint density, available at:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution

Comment: @ABDELRAHMANS.ABDELRAHMAN Sorry, it was a typo. Yes, I mean pdf,re-edited now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the probability density function for $Y$ at $y$, multiplied by the conditional probability that $X$ is within the domain of the integration (ie $a< X\leqslant b$) when given that $Y=y$.

$$\int_a^b f_{\small X,Y}\!(x,y)\,\mathrm d x= f_{\small Y}\!(y)\,\mathsf P(a\,{<}\,X\,{\leqslant}\,b\mid Y=y)$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As both are continuous variables, is $P(a\leq X\leq b\mid Y=y)$ suppose to be zero?

Comment: @LING No. You may have a non-zero conditional probability when conditioned on a null event.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was thinking about this for some time, and I have three ideas that all could convinced myself, and I don't know which is right. **If they are not independent** 1. $\mathbb{P}(a\leq X\leq b|Y=y)=\mathbb{P}(a\leq X\leq b)$ as $Y$ is continuous, it's meaningless to condition on specific value. 2 $\mathbb{P}(a\leq X\leq b|Y=y)=0$ as $\mathbb{P}(Y=y)=0$ 3. $\mathbb{P}(a\leq X\leq b|Y=y)=1$ from the joint distribution graph

Comment: If the joint and marginal density functions do exist, then the conditional density function can be used, and by definition the conditional probability mass of $a<X\leqslant b$ is the integral over the domain of the conditional probability density of $X$ under that condition. Basically... $$\begin{align}\mathbb P(a\lt X\leqslant b\mid Y=y)~&=~\int_a^b f_{\small X\mid Y}(x\mid y)\,\mathrm d x\\&=\int_a^b\dfrac{f_{\small X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{\small Y}(y)}\,\mathrm d x\end{align}$$

Comment: 1. It is meaningful to condition on the event that a continuous random variable realises a specific value--even when the probability of that variable doing so has zero measure--as long as the relevant density functions exist. If $X$ and $Y$ are dependent, the probability that $X$ is in an interval shall be dependent on the value of $Y$ too.  If nothing else, it allows us to calculate $\int_c^d f_{\small Y}(y)\,\mathbb P(a<X\leqslant b\mid Y=y)\,\mathrm d y$